# Drawing Geometric Shapes in Java using Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently trying to build a Java Application (using Swing) to simply draw some lines on the Main-Window by clicking on the window.

I currently managed to write a program that works. The following code leads to the expected result, but I don't like the way it is working.

In my code the program is redrawing all the lines. Also the ones that were already existing (and shown up). I assume this is not a good practice because this leads to a lot of unnecessary work in the case the lineArray contains a lot of elements.

Is there a better way to draw the lines? Can I keep the already displayed lines somehow and add only the new one?

```
public class DrawPlane extends JLabel {

public ArrayList<myLine> lineArray;

public DrawPlane() {
    this.setOpaque(false);
    
    lineArray = new ArrayList<>();
    
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            lineArray.add(new myLine(e.getX(), e.getY(), 0, 0));
        }
        
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            myLine last = lineArray.get( lineArray.size() - 1 );
            last.x2 = e.getX();
            last.y2 = e.getY();
            lineArray.set(lineArray.size() - 1, last);
            repaint();
        }
    });
}

public void DrawLines(Graphics g) {
    lineArray.forEach(lineItem -> g.drawLine(lineItem.x1, lineItem.y1, lineItem.x2, lineItem.y2));
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    DrawLines(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    }
}
```

Note: myLine is defined in an additional file and is a basic class with only four properties (int) x1, y1, x2 and y2.

Regards Michael

Comment: Nothing wrong with approach if you want to draw previous lines. Method names begin lower case in Java btw: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions

Comment: You have to redraw all the lines each time you repaint.  That's how Swing painting works.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

Comment: *Is there a better way to draw the lines?* - there is nothing wrong with your current approach, however, check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the two common ways to do this. You are currently using one of the approaches. Read the information and decide which approach is best for your requirement.